# How to search for text and get the other values present at that same location in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to search if the text "Swiss" exists and if yes then I want to capture the value of "Roger" which is against it.

```html
<TABLE ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN="TOP"><TR><TD ><DIV CLASS=MONOSIZE3><NOBR><FONT COLOR="BLUE">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Place&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thing
</FONT></BR><FONT COLOR="BLACK">&nbsp;&nbsp;Roger&nbsp;&nbsp;Swiss&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tennis&nbsp;Order
</FONT></BR><FONT COLOR="BLACK">&nbsp;&nbsp;Mathew&nbsp;&nbsp;Aussie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cricket
</FONT></BR></NOBR></DIV></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

er" (which is against it)

**Name**   **Place**         **Thing**

**Roger**  **Swiss**           **Tennis**

**Mathew**  **Aussie**           **Cricket**

Thank You!

Comment: Post what efforts you have made to solve this issue..

Comment: Also, paste the html dom of the table

Comment: @nosybuddy, Please post your html code in proper format

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help you. It search for the string and get the left side string.

```
    String searchStr="Swiss";
    String otherStr=null;
    String currStr=null;
    List<WebElement> lstRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tr/td/div/nobr/font"));
    for(WebElement row:lstRows){
        currStr=row.getText().trim();
        if(currStr.contains(searchStr)){
            otherStr=currStr.split(" ")[0];
            break;
        }
    }
if(otherStr!=null)
        System.out.println(otherStr);
else
        System.out.println("unable to find the text"+searchStr);
```